# WPF TreeView subnodes offset

Tags: wpf, treeview, nodes, offset

Is there any standard way to change nodes offset at the left side of `TreeView` in WPF?
I need to get something that looks like a `ListBox` with a grouping `Expander`, but I have to use `TreeView` for data representation.

**For Example**

This

```
-TreeViewItem0
|--TreeViewItem01
|--TreeViewItem01
+TreeViewItem1
```

Becomes

```
-TreeViewItem0
TreeViewItem01
TreeViewItem01
+TreeViewItem1
```

Comment: How do you add nodes to the tree?

Comment: How about using ListBox with groupping?

Comment: Yes, It is better to use a ListBox with grouping. Thank you.